# List of objects with async Task methods, execute all concurrently

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

Given the following:

```
BlockingCollection<MyObject> collection;

public class MyObject
{
   public async Task<ReturnObject> DoWork() 
   {       
      (...) 
      return await SomeIOWorkAsync();
   }
}
```

What would be the correct/most performant way to execute **all** DoWork() tasks asynchronously on **all** MyObjects in *collection* concurrently (while capturing the return object), ideally with a sensible thread limit though (I believe the Task Factory/ThreadPool does some management here)?

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of the WhenAll extension method.

```
var combinedTask = await Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(x => x.DoWork());
```

It will start all tasks concurrently and waits for all to finish.

Comment: Is there a different way if I want to capture every individual DoWork() return immediately instead of waiting for all items to complete?

Comment: `collection.Select(x => x.DoWork())` returns an `IEnumerable<Task>`, so you can do normal `Task` operations like `ContinueWith`

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadPool` manages the number of *threads* running, but that won't help you much with asynchronous `Task`s.

Because of that, you need something else. One way to do this is to utilize `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow:

```
int limit = …;
IEnumerable<MyObject> collection = …;

var block = new ActionBlock<MyObject>(
    o => o.DoWork(),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = limit });

foreach (var obj in collection)
    block.Post(o);

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the correct/most performant way to execute all DoWork() tasks asynchronously on all MyObjects in collection concurrently (while capturing the return object), ideally with a sensible thread limit

The easiest way to do that is with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
ReturnObject[] results = await Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(x => x.DoWork()));
```

This will invoke `DoWork` on all `MyObjects` in the collection and then wait for them all to complete. The thread pool handles all throttling sensibly.

> Is there a different way if I want to capture every individual DoWork() return immediately instead of waiting for all items to complete?

Yes, you can use the method described by [Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time.aspx) and [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx). I have a [similar solution](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskExtensions) in my AsyncEx library (available via NuGet), which you can use like this:

```
// "tasks" is of type "Task<ReturnObject>[]"
var tasks = collection.Select(x => x.DoWork()).OrderByCompletion();
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
  var result = await task;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I understood “sensible thread limit” as “sensible limit on the degree of parallelism” and a simple `Select()` isn't enough for that.

Comment: I understood it as "without consuming a huge amount of resources even if the collection is large". If the op does want to specify the degree of parallelism then your answer is better (I +1'ed it for that reason). Mine is an alternative option if the op doesn't need to specify the degree of parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

My comment was a bit cryptic, so I though I'd add this answer:

```
List<Task<ReturnObject>> workTasks =
  collection.Select( o => o.DoWork() ).ToList();

List<Task> resultTasks =
  workTasks.Select( o => o.ContinueWith( t =>
      {
        ReturnObject r = t.Result;
        // do something with the result
      },
      // if you want to run this on the UI thread
      TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    )
  )
  .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll( resultTasks );
```